# How do i open this git repository source forge

Tags: git, hyperlink, sourceforge

Its a silly question but here you go:

I want to open this git repository from source forge but i dont know how to open this link:

git clone http://git.code.sf.net/p/tidirectlink/code tidirectlink-code

from this link:

http://sourceforge.net/p/tidirectlink/code/ref/master/

Help Please!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a command to download it all to your computer with Git, it's not a link.

```
git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/tidirectlink/code tidirectlink-code
```

You'll need to have [Git](http://git-scm.com) installed and then you can run it in the terminal or Git Bash or a GUI, and it will clone the repo to your computer.